# center items inside the child div html css

Tags: html, css, reactjs

i want to center align the div present inside the div
the output should look like this
[image]

but its not center aligning the:

```
 <div className="design">
                <div className="design_h1">
                    <h1 >Lets create the future <strong>together</strong></h1>
                    <button className="trail">Start your 10 day trail now</button>
                </div>
 </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.design {
  flex: 1;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.design_h1 /*whole right side */ {
  color: rgb(184, 181, 181);
  border: 2px solid white;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url(faded.jpg) no-repeat center center/cover;
}
.design_h1 h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

my output look like this
[image]

ive posted detailed code here
https://github.com/mareyam/htmlcsss

Answer (score 1):

Look into below code for reference, i am not giving code to just copy and paste, refer and learn, its not that's hard.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.center { 
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  border: 3px solid green; 
}

.center p {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Center with position and transform</h2>

<p>In this example, we use positioning and the transform property to vertically and horizontally center the div element:</p>

<div class="center">
  <p>I am vertically and horizontally centered.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

A simple example by **W3SCHOOLS** is [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_align_transform)

BEST OF LUCK

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the H1 and button in another div and center that relative to the outer div like so:

```
<div className="design">
    <div className="design_h1">
        <div className="centered-div">
              <h1 >Lets create the future <strong>together</strong></h1>
              <button className="trail">Start your 10 day trail now</button>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.h1_design {
     position: relative;
 }
.centered-div {
     position: absolute;
     top: 50%;
     left: 50%;
     transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try `display: grid`:

```html
 <div className="design">
                <div className="design_h1">
                    <h1 >Lets create the future <strong>together</strong></h1>
                    <button className="trail">Start your 10 day trail now</button>
                </div>
 </div>
```

```css
.design {
  flex: 1;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.design_h1 /*whole right side */ {
  color: rgb(184, 181, 181);
  border: 2px solid white;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url(faded.jpg) no-repeat center center/cover;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  grid-template-columns: 100%;
  grid-template-rows: 100%;
}
.design_h1 h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  grid-row: 1 / span 1;
  grid-column: 1 / span 1
}
```